# Throws NullPointerException while retrieving data from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

First of all, sorry for my bad English !

I have an Activity ( say *MainActivity.java* ) and a class ( say *AsynkTaskClass.java* ).

AsynkTaskClass.java contains an **AsynkTask**. I am calling this *AsynkTask* from *MainActivity.java*.

Before calling this *AsynkTask*, I am saving some data using *SharedPreferences*.

From the **onPostExecute** function of **AsynkTask**, I am calling a normal function ( say *displaySharedData()* )which defined in *MainActivity.java*. There I am trying to retrieve the data I stored using *SharedPreferences*. Then It shows a **NullPointerException**. But I can access the Shared data from anywhere other than this *displaySharedData()* function.

This is the Log Output:

```
W/dalvikvm(3896): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(3896): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(3896): java.lang.NullPointerExceptionE/AndroidRuntime(3896):   at com.samApp.project.samApp.ui.MainActivity.displaySharedData(MainActivity.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at com.samApp.project.samApp.s3.AsynkTaskClass$UploadImage.onPostExecute(AsynkTaskClass.java:264)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at com.samApp.project.samApp.s3.AsynkTaskClass$UploadImage.onPostExecute(AsynkTaskClass.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
    public SharedPreferences myData;
    public String mySharedData="com.samApp.project.samApp.ui";
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedBundle) {
super.onCreate(savedBundle);
    myData = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
editor = myData.edit();
editor.commit();


attachfileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_SELECTED);

        }
    });

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case PHOTO_SELECTED:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                Log.d("URIsssss", String.valueOf(selectedImage));
                AsynkTaskClass obj = new AsynkTaskClass ();
                AsynkTaskClass.s3context=this;
                obj.new UploadImage().execute(selectedImage);

            }
        }
    }
}
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    editor.putString("name", "MeSSi");
    editor.commit();

    }


public void displaySharedData()
    {  

        Log.d("SharedData",myData.getString("name","")); // line No : 52
    }
}
```

**AsynkTaskClass.java**

```
public class AsynkTaskClass {

MainActivity mainActvtyObj = new MainActivity();
public static Context s3context;


protected void onPostExecute(S3TaskResult result) {
            if(dialog != null)
                dialog.dismiss();

            if (result.getErrorMessage() != null) {

                displayErrorAlert(
                        AsynkTaskClass.s3context.getString(R.string.upload_failure_title),
                    result.getErrorMessage());
            }

            mainActvtyObj.displaySharedData();

        }
 }
```

So, Any Help ??

Comment: What is at line `45`? you can access `preferences` from any where but you need proper `Context` to access.

Comment: Why don't you show us some code?

Comment: We can`t help you without code of `MainActivity`

Comment: Please show code of MainActivity.java. And specify which is the line MainActivity.java:52.

Comment: Sorry, I will add the code ASAP !

Comment: I think in `your_method` you need to pass one parameter as `context`? Post your code, then it will be easy for everyone to help you

Comment: I Added the code !! plz have a look !

Comment: @BBHeeMAA `myData` is null

Comment: Where are `myData` and `mainActvtyObj` initialized and how?

Comment: @BBHeeMAA is   `mainActvtyObj` an instance of Activity class

Comment: mainActvtyObj is an instance of Activity class !!

Comment: @BBHeeMAA never instantiate activity class. It is wrong.

Comment: @Raghunandan You can have an instance of Activity without instantiating it yourself..

Comment: @BBHeeMAA You probably forgot to initialize myData

Comment: @BBHeeMAA If not include the initialization of myData in your question

Comment: @AdamToth : Code Updated , Sorry for the in convenience.

Comment: @laalto : Code Updated , Sorry for the in convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a working solution.

I don't know whether It is perfect! But it works well..

I replaced the *displaySharedData()* calling statement i.e. `mainActvtyObj.displaySharedData();` to the following :

`((MainActivity) s3context).displaySharedData();`

Now It Works Great !!

Answer (score 2):

```
MainActivity mainActvtyObj = new MainActivity();
```

Never instantiate activity classes with `new`.

For example, their lifecycle callbacks such as `onCreate()` are not run. You init your `myData` in `onCreate()` and it remains null in this activity instance.

Instead, pass a reference to your activity object to the async task as a parameter.